# Truststore and Keystore Definitions

Tags: keystore, encryption-asymmetric, truststore

What's the difference between a keystore and a truststore?

Answer (score 303, accepted):

A keystore contains private keys, and the certificates with their corresponding public keys.

A truststore contains certificates from other parties that you expect to communicate with, or from Certificate Authorities that you trust to identify other parties.

Comment: Although this should be true in practice, they can (and often are) one in the same. You can actually import a private key and a public certificate into the [java home]/jre/lib/security/cacerts default "truststore". The keytool utility does not make a distinction in the two terms, only in store types (i.e. - JKS vs. PKCS12). For that matter, Java does the same thing in the source code. You create a java.security.KeyStore, and use a trust manager to manage the certificates in it, but there is no TrustStore class.

Comment: Java does not have a `TrustStore` *per se*. Or I could not find it in the java docs (for example, `java.security.TrustStore`). When we want to trust a Certificate Authority, it is trusted through a `KeyStore` (and the `KeyStore` is passed into the `TrustManagerFactory`).

Comment: It is worth mentioning that `KeyStore.load(InputStream is, char[] password)` ([docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html#load%28java.io.InputStream,%20char[]%29)) can take a null password and it then will give access to public certificates. That is, the code that wants to browse a truststore does not need to know it password (for very good reasons!)

Answer (score 95):

1. A keystore contains private keys. You only need this if you are
   a server, or if the server requires client authentication.
2. A truststore contains CA certificates to trust. If your server’s
   certificate is signed by a recognized CA, the default truststore
   that ships with the JRE will already trust it (because it already
   trusts trustworthy CAs), so you don’t need to build your own,
   or to add anything to the one from the JRE.

[Source](http://mynotes.wordpress.com/2009/08/04/difference-between-keystore-truststore)

Answer (score 86):

In a SSL handshake the purpose of **trustStore is to verify credentials** and the purpose of **keyStore is to provide credential**.

**keyStore**

keyStore in Java stores private key and certificates corresponding to their public keys and require if you are SSL Server or SSL requires client authentication.

**TrustStore**

TrustStore stores certificates from third party, your Java application communicate or certificates signed by CA(certificate authorities like Verisign, Thawte, Geotrust or GoDaddy) which can be used to identify third party.

**TrustManager**

TrustManager determines whether remote connection should be trusted or not i.e. whether remote party is who it claims to and KeyManager decides which authentication credentials should be sent to the remote host for authentication during SSL handshake.

If you are an SSL Server you will use private key during key exchange algorithm and send certificates corresponding to your public keys to client, this certificate is acquired from keyStore. On SSL client side, if its written in Java, it will use certificates stored in trustStore to verify identity of Server. SSL certificates are most commonly comes as **.cer** file which is added into keyStore or trustStore by using any key management utility e.g. **keytool**.

Source: [http://javarevisited.blogspot.ch](http://javarevisited.blogspot.ch/2012/09/difference-between-truststore-vs-keyStore-Java-SSL.html)

Answer (score 31):

You may also be interested in the write-up from Sun, as part of the standard JSSE documentation:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Stores

Typically, the trust store is used to store only public keys, for verification purposes, such as with X.509 authentication. For manageability purposes, it's quite common for admins or developers to simply conflate the two into a single store.

Comment: Gives a 404 unfortunately

Comment: @ChrisBeach - have updated the link to the correct one on the Oracle site.

Comment: The truststore is used to store *trusted signer certificates.*

Answer (score 15):

> In Java, what's the difference between a keystore and a truststore?

Here's the description from the Java docs at [Java Secure Socket Extension (JSSE) Reference Guide](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html). I don't think it tells you anything different from what others have said. But it does provide the official reference.

> **keystore/truststore**
>
> A keystore is a database of key material. Key material is used for a variety of purposes, including authentication and data integrity.
>   Various types of keystores are available, including PKCS12 and
>   Oracle's JKS.
>
> Generally speaking, keystore information can be grouped into two categories: key entries and trusted certificate entries. A key entry
>   consists of an entity's identity and its private key, and can be used
>   for a variety of cryptographic purposes. In contrast, a trusted
>   certificate entry contains only a public key in addition to the
>   entity's identity. Thus, a trusted certificate entry cannot be used
>   where a private key is required, such as in a
>   javax.net.ssl.KeyManager. In the JDK implementation of JKS, a keystore
>   may contain both key entries and trusted certificate entries.
>
> A truststore is a keystore that is used when making decisions about what to trust. If you receive data from an entity that you
>   already trust, and if you can verify that the entity is the one that
>   it claims to be, then you can assume that the data really came from
>   that entity.
>
> An entry should only be added to a truststore if the user trusts that entity. By either generating a key pair or by importing a
>   certificate, the user gives trust to that entry. Any entry in the
>   truststore is considered a trusted entry.
>
> It may be useful to have two different keystore files: one containing just your key entries, and the other containing your
>   trusted certificate entries, including CA certificates. The former
>   contains private information, whereas the latter does not. Using two
>   files instead of a single keystore file provides a cleaner separation
>   of the logical distinction between your own certificates (and
>   corresponding private keys) and others' certificates. To provide more
>   protection for your private keys, store them in a keystore with
>   restricted access, and provide the trusted certificates in a more
>   publicly accessible keystore if needed.

Answer (score 7):

1. First and major difference between trustStore and keyStore is that trustStore is used by TrustManager to determine whether remote connection should be trusted, keyStore is used from KeyManager deciding which authentication credentials should be sent to the remote host for authentication during SSL handshake.
2. Another difference is that keyStore theoretically contains private keys required only if you are running a Server in SSL connection or you have enabled client authentication on server side and on the other hand trustStore stores public key or certificates from CA (Certificate Authorities) which are used to trust remote party or SSL connection.

   In fact you can store in the same file both private and public keys,
   given that the the tool to manage those file is the same (keytool),
   so *you could* use a single file for both the purposes, but you
   probably *should not*.
3. At least on my Mac OSX the default keyStore is `${user.home}/.keystore`, and the default trustStore is `/System/Library/Java/Support/CoreDeploy.bundle/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts`.

   If you want to override them you should add the JVM parameters
   `-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore /path/to/keyStore` or
   `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore /path/to/trustStore`. You might also
   need to set the keyStore password in case of
   `java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password must not be
   null`, using the parameter
   `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password` or `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password`

*Main Source:*

> http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/difference-between-truststore-vs-keyStore-Java-SSL.html

Answer (score 0):

Keystore is used to store private key and identity certificates that a specific program should present to both parties (server or client) for verification.

Truststore is used to store certificates from Certified Authorities (CA) that verify the certificate presented by the server in SSL connection.

This article for reference https://www.educative.io/edpresso/keystore-vs-truststore