# Integration testing with Spring RestTemplate, Maven and HTTPS -- Client connection?

Tags: java, maven-2, ssl, https

I saw this [post](http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/integration_testing_with_http_https) from Matt Riable which shows how to set up Integration Testing with HTTP, HTTPS and Maven. I found it very interesting. I have got my project generating the keystore using the [keytool-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/keytool-maven-plugin/). But this doesn't allow me generate a trust store...

I guess I am missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318441/truststore-and-keystore-definitions) may be related.  `keystore` file itself can serve as `truststore` unless there is a need to distinguish between them.