# Jira Rest API Using Java

Tags: java, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

Am trying to calling Jira using Jira Rest Api. While creating a connection am getting below error.

Jira URL: https://jira.dv.xxxxx.com/rest/api/2/search?&fields=status,projectkey&jql=clientId%3DTABC+and+taskid%3DTABC-2

**Java Code:**

```
public static HttpURLConnection getJiraClientConnection(final URL url) throws IOException{
        PropertiesManager prMgr = PropertiesManager.getInstance();
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod(CommonConstants.GET);
        conn.setRequestProperty(CommonConstants.ACCEPT, CommonConstants.ACCEPTTYPE);
        conn.setRequestProperty(CommonConstants.AUTHORIZATION, CommonConstants.BASIC + prMgr.getPassword());
}
```

**Error:**

```
        javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1979)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1086)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
```

I googled for this error, I was not getting any correct solution for this.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This answer has some options that may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353849/received-fatal-alert-handshake-failure-through-sslhandshakeexception

I would first check your SSL version compatibility and certificate trust path.

Answer (score 0):

From another user, "This error means your java truststore doesnt have ssl certificate for service you are trying to connect." [javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19046639/javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception). And a more in depth trouble shooting guide here [Received fatal alert: handshake_failure through SSLHandshakeException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353849/received-fatal-alert-handshake-failure-through-sslhandshakeexception)