# How do you add a .p12 certificate to an Android device?

Tags: android, ssl

I'm having trouble loading a .p12 certificate to my Android project. Here is a chunk of source code:

```
char[] password = "<my pass>".toCharArray();
FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream("<name of cert>");
KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
keystore.load(fIn, password);
```

On line 2 an error occurred opening cert file.

How can I properly add the cert file to my Android program?

Answer (score 0):

> ...
>
> In Android, I see people programmatically install keystore in the
>   following way (The code is from Android developer blog):
>
> ```
> byte[] keystore = . . (read from a PKCS#12 keystore)
>
> Intent installIntent = KeyChain.createInstallIntent();
> installIntent.putExtra(KeyChain.EXTRA_PKCS12, keystore);
> startActivityForResult(installIntent, INSTALL_KEYSTORE_CODE);
> ```
>
> I also see people programmatically install only the certificate
>   wrapped inside keystore:
>
> ```
> Intent intent = KeyChain.createInstallIntent();
> intent.putExtra(KeyChain.EXTRA_CERTIFICATE, cert);
> startActivity(intent);
> ```
>
> ...which leads   --@Leem.fin
>   [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19930012)

may find that the following link a better place to start:

https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#signing-manually

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
File cert = new File("mnt/sdcard/" + filename + ".p12");
InputStream inputStreamFromDownload = null;

keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
inputStreamFromDownload = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(cert));

Log.i("Certificate", inputStreamFromDownload.available() + "");
```

Comment: Where i must place my .p12 certificate? Main problem is that i don't know from what place android read certificate. I use only internal storage, i don't have sdcard. I put .p12 file into Android folder and data folder. I did't find folder of my debugable app on device.

Comment: @user3437564 did you find out where to place the certificate?