# Android javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found

Tags: java, android, certificate, ssl-certificate, android-ksoap2

I am getting the issue when i change my http url to https..

for example my first url is and application working fine:

**http://hello.com/app/service.asmx**

when i change the url with https then it's crashed

**https://hello.com/app/service.asmx**

any solution?Thanks Alot in advance

this is my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Button btn_signin;
EditText et_username;
EditText et_password;
Button btn_login;
Button btn_create_login;
String username;
String password;
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
ProgressDialog pDialog;
ProgressDialog prgDialog;
TextView errorMsg;
TextView tv_forgotpass;
TextView tv_login_num;
AlertDialog alert;



private final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";

private final String URL = urls.base_url;
private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/Login";
private final String METHOD_NAME = "Login";

// SoapPrimitive response;
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport;
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope;
SoapObject request;

String message;// = c.getString("message");
int sessionid;// = c.getInt("sessionid");
int saleid;// = c.getInt("saleid");
String name;// = c.getString("name");
String email;// = c.getString("email");
String defaultmsisdn;// = c.getString("defaultmsisdn");
String associatedmsisdn;
int associatedsaleid;
String associatedmsisdn1;
int associatedsaleid1;

// final List<String> AssociatedArray = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> AssociatedArray = new ArrayList<String>();
String associatedArray = null;

List myArray = new ArrayList<String>();


SharedPreferences progress;
SharedPreferences.Editor progress_editor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    progress = getSharedPreferences("SelfCarePref", MODE_PRIVATE);

    progress_editor = progress.edit();
    progress_editor.clear();
    progress_editor.commit();


    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }



    et_username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_Mobile);
    et_password = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editText_password);

    btn_signin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_signin);
    btn_create_login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_create_login);
    tv_forgotpass = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_forgotpass);
    tv_login_num = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_login_num);

    prgDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    // Set Progress Dialog Text
    prgDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    // Set Cancelable as False
    prgDialog.setCancelable(false);

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

    btn_create_login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            et_username.setText("");
            et_password.setText("");
        }
    });

    btn_signin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            loginAction();
        }
    });

    tv_login_num.setText(Html.fromHtml("<u>Login with Number</u>"));
    tv_login_num.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginNumber.class);

            startActivity(intent);
            et_username.setText("");
            et_password.setText("");
        }
    });

    tv_forgotpass.setText(Html.fromHtml("<u>Forgot Credentials</u>"));

    tv_forgotpass.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Forgot.class);

            startActivity(intent);
            et_username.setText("");
            et_password.setText("");
            // finish();
        }
    });

    //Check if contact is already exists or not in Contact list
    /*if(contactExists(this,"0344"))
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"baba exists",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this," not exists",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }*/

}

public  boolean contactExists(Activity _activity,String number){
      Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,Uri.encode(number));

     String[] mPhoneNumberProjection = { PhoneLookup._ID, PhoneLookup.NUMBER, PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME };

    Cursor cur = _activity.getContentResolver().query(lookupUri,mPhoneNumberProjection, null, null, null);
  try {
        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
          // if contact are in contact list it will return true
          return true;
       }} finally {
           if (cur != null)
              cur.close();
      }
         //if contact are not match that means contact are not added
        return false;
    }



private void loginAction() {
    request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    Log.d("SelfCare", "NAMESPACE= " + NAMESPACE);
    Log.d("SelfCare", "METHOD_NAME= " + METHOD_NAME);

    // EditText userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    username = et_username.getText().toString();
    // EditText userPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    String user_Password = et_password.getText().toString();
    String apptypecode = "TXDIY0006";

    Log.d("SelfCare", "user_Name= " + username);
    Log.d("SelfCare", "password= " + user_Password);

    /*
     * request.addProperty("username", user_Name);
     * request.addProperty("password", user_Password);
     * request.addProperty("apptypecode", apptypecode);
     */

    // Pass value for userName variable of the web service
    if (username.trim().equals("")) {
        alertDialog("Please Enter Username");
        et_username.requestFocus();
    } else if (user_Password.equals("")) {
        alertDialog("Please Enter Your Password");
        et_password.requestFocus();
    } else {

        progress_editor = progress.edit();
        progress_editor.putString("username", username);
        progress_editor.putString("password", user_Password);

        progress_editor.commit();

        PropertyInfo unameProp = new PropertyInfo();
        unameProp.setName("username");// Define the variable name in the web
                                        // service method
        unameProp.setValue(username);// set value for userName variable
        unameProp.setType(String.class);// Define the type of the variable
        request.addProperty(unameProp);// Pass properties to the variable

        // Pass value for Password variable of the web service
        PropertyInfo passwordProp = new PropertyInfo();
        passwordProp.setName("password");
        passwordProp.setValue(user_Password);
        passwordProp.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(passwordProp);

        PropertyInfo apptypecodes = new PropertyInfo();
        apptypecodes.setName("apptypecode");
        apptypecodes.setValue(apptypecode);
        apptypecodes.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(apptypecodes);

        new AsyncCallWS().execute();
    }

}

/*@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    progress_editor = progress.edit();
    progress_editor.clear();
    progress_editor.commit();
    super.onDestroy();
}*/

private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {

            envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            Log.d("SelfCare", "request= " + request);
            // androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL, 60000);

            Log.d("SelfCare", "androidHttpTransport= "
                    + androidHttpTransport);

            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            Log.d("SelfCare", "response= " + response);
            /*
             * Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Response= " +
             * response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             */
            String jsonResponse = "";
            jsonResponse = response.toString();

            // A JSONTokener is needed in order to use JSONObject correctly
            JSONTokener jsonTokener = new JSONTokener(jsonResponse);
            // Pass a JSONTokener to the JSONObject constructor
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonTokener);
            JSONArray data = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");

            if (data != null) {

                // looping through All nodes
                for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
                    message = c.getString("message");
                    sessionid = c.getInt("sessionid");
                    saleid = c.getInt("saleid");
                    name = c.getString("name");
                    email = c.getString("email");
                    defaultmsisdn = c.getString("defaultmsisdn");
                    associatedArray = c.getString("AssociatedArray");

                    AssociatedArray.add(associatedArray);

                    Log.d("SelfCare farhan aarray", "AssociatedArray= "
                            + AssociatedArray);

                    // Log.d("SelfCare farhan aarray", "AssociatedArray= " +
                    // myArray);

                    /*
                     * associatedmsisdn = c.getString("associatedmsisdn");
                     * associatedsaleid = c.getInt("associatedsaleid");
                     * associatedmsisdn1 = c.getString("associatedmsisdn1");
                     * associatedsaleid1 = c.getInt("associatedsaleid1");
                     * 
                     * Log.d("SelfCare", "message= " + message);
                     * Log.d("SelfCare", "sessionid= " + sessionid);
                     * Log.d("SelfCare", "associatedmsisdn= " +
                     * associatedmsisdn); Log.d("SelfCare",
                     * "associatedsaleid= " + associatedsaleid);
                     * Log.d("SelfCare", "associatedmsisdn1= " +
                     * associatedmsisdn1); Log.d("SelfCare",
                     * "associatedsaleid1= " + associatedsaleid1);
                     */

                }

                /*
                 * Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Success",
                 * Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 */

            } else {
                /*
                 * Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error",
                 * Toast.LENGTH_LONG) .show();
                 */}

            /*
             * TextView results = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_error);
             * results.setText(response.toString());
             */

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // alertDialog(e.toString());
            /*
             * Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(),
             * Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             */
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute");
        // tv.setText(fahren + "° F");

        pDialog.dismiss();

        if (message != null) {

            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("Login Successful.")) {
                if (defaultmsisdn.equalsIgnoreCase("null") && saleid == 0) {
                    et_username.setText("");
                    et_password.setText("");
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            AssociateMsisdn.class);
                    intent.putExtra("username", username);
                    intent.putExtra("sessionid", sessionid);
                    intent.putExtra("name", name);
                    intent.putExtra("email", email);
                    intent.putExtra("AssociatedArray", associatedArray);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    // alertDialog("Open the Associate MSISDN Class.");
                } else {
                    et_username.setText("");
                    et_password.setText("");
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            MainMenu.class);
                    intent.putExtra("name", name);
                    intent.putExtra("username", username);
                    intent.putExtra("defaultmsisdn", defaultmsisdn);
                    intent.putExtra("sessionid", sessionid);
                    intent.putExtra("saleid", saleid);
                    intent.putExtra("email", email);
                    intent.putExtra("AssociatedArray", associatedArray);

                    Log.d("SelfCare farhan aarray put", "AssociatedArray= "
                            + AssociatedArray);
                    // intent.putStringArrayListExtra("AssociatedArray",
                    // AssociatedArray);

                    /*
                     * intent.putExtra("associatedmsisdn",
                     * associatedmsisdn);
                     * intent.putExtra("associatedsaleid",
                     * associatedsaleid);
                     * intent.putExtra("associatedmsisdn1",
                     * associatedmsisdn1);
                     * intent.putExtra("associatedsaleid1",
                     * associatedsaleid1);
                     */

                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            } else {
                alertDialog(message);
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" +message ,
                // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } else {
            alertDialog(getResources().getString(R.string.server_error));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        // Log.i(TAG, "onProgressUpdate");
    }

}

public void alertDialog(String Error) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setMessage(Error).setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // do things
                    alert.cancel();
                }
            });
    alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}

public void alertDialogSuccess(String Error) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setMessage(Error).setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // do things
                    /*
                     * Intent intent = new Intent( getApplicationContext(),
                     * ActivateUser.class); intent.putExtra("username",
                     * username); startActivity(intent);
                     */
                }
            });
    alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}

public void alert() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            MainActivity.this);
    // set title
    builder1.setTitle("Email Verification via SMS");
    builder1.setMessage("farhan shah");
    builder1.setCancelable(true);
    builder1.setPositiveButton("Yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    builder1.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
    alert11.show();
}

public void navigatetoHomeActivity() {
    Intent homeIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainMenu.class);
    homeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(homeIntent);
 }

}
```

Comment: Are you using a self-signed server-certificate? Then you have to explicitly trust this certificate.

Comment: @Christopher dear how i can explicitly trust this certificate??

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318441/truststore-and-keystore-definitions