# What is truststore and keystore

Tags: tls1.2

I am interconnecting two services by my code. Those two services exposed over TLS 1.2

While I do that I found there is some slight mismatch in encryption standard on `AES`. I do not have authority to change encryption standards on these two nodes. I just need the interaction by code has to go well without affecting `tls` layer. How could I run my code successfully.

Is I could do anything with `truststore and keystore` to make my code operable.

Comment: The question is quite unclear. Can you describe what your code is doing in more detail?

Comment: Right now I am doing PoC interconnecting two `web services` which is on `TLS1.2`, even I do not carry code access, rather I do things which are work around. And I cannot disclose encryption std., rather one thing which I can say both side on `AES`, I mean kind of with variation from one another.

Comment: Here is the clarity [truststore and keystore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318441/truststore-and-keystore-definitions)

Comment: In java `cacerts` file handles the `truststore`. For `Application Server UNIX user`, if file access permission,- `rw` is there, Application Server could handle secure layer communication. No update on that file is required, provided proper `JKS` file is in use. `JKS` holds public & private keys, that needs to be updated to turn portal to secured layer.

Comment: I hope `-trustcacerts` option has some implication in making `cacerts` file entry automatically while updating keystore file,- `.JKS` for secure layer.